# about replace methods in string in js

Tags: javascript, string, replace

```
let code = document.querySelector('.Nform').innerHTML;
localStorage.setItem('code',JSON.stringify(code));
let finalCode = code.replace(/ <p class="removeElement" onclick="removeElement()"></p> /g , ` ` );
console.log(finalCode);
document.querySelector('.code').value =`${finalCode}`;
```

Hello , I want to use / /g to replace this html element from code but p tag have close element (/p) so how can escape it make sure i want to send this by code no sting,
thanks

Comment: it should be `<\/p>`

Comment: when i use <\/p> do not replace anything      let finalCode = code.replace(/<div class="removeElement" onclick="removeElement()"><\/div>/g,` `);

Comment: I think it's because of the parentheses, they should be escaped too. please try this: `let finalCode = code.replace(/<div class="removeElement" onclick="removeElement\(\)"><\/div>/g, ' ');`

Comment: @AhmedEssam I just added an answer. Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your regex, You have to escape these four special characters **:** `"`, `(`, `)`, `/`

Demo **:**

```js
let originalCode = document.querySelector('.Nform').innerHTML;

console.log(originalCode);

let finalCode = originalCode.replace(/<p class=\"removeElement\" onclick=\"removeElement\(\)\">Paragraph 1<\/p>/g, '');

console.log(finalCode);
```

```html
<div class="Nform">
  <p class="removeElement" onclick="removeElement()">Paragraph 1</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the parentheses, they should be escaped too. please try this: let finalCode = code.replace(/</div>/g, ' '); –

by GrafiCode https://stackoverflow.com/users/5334486/graficode